# Workbench Access field cannot be used for access control

Tags: nodes, workbench

I have set up [Workbench Access](https://drupal.org/project/workbench_access) and [Workbench Moderation](https://drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation) and it is working in creating revisions for the Main Page Content section but when I go to add additional fields using the Workbench Access control field checkbox, I cannot enable the field and a message displays

> This field cannot be used for access control

How is it possible to allow a custom field to be added to access control?  I've enabled the correct content type, set up vocabularies and set the Access control fields with the node reference field from the content type.

[image: field screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

The fields were enabled all along, the main issue was targeting the problem.  Only my body field was displaying on the node draft. I had several other custom content fields in the node but they weren't displaying in the Draft.  The site is built using Context and Views so was I had to do was clone Draft versions of those View Blocks and View Blocks.  Setting that up can be a little confusing but I found good documentation here

[Draft Revision Blocks](https://drupal.org/node/1901892)